# Chase QuickPay money sent to the wrong account

Tags: online-banking

If money is sent by Chase QuickPay to the wrong account, how I can I get it back?  The money was sent to the wrong telephone number; it went to someone I don't know.  Chase refuses to help.  They suggested I call the wrong number and ask the person to give the money back.  I have called the number and left voice messages. However, no one has returned my calls; they have not returned the money.

Thanks in advance for our help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a dispute between you and Chase; it's not really an area where we can give personal finance advice.

Comment: I'm afraid they're probably right. The bank did exactly what you told them to do. It isn't their fault you told them to do the wrong thing, nor is it their responsibility to try to correct it. Unless you want to try getting legal assistance to recover the funds, or at least threaten to, I suspect you're going to have to take the loss.

Comment: I'm sorry about the predicament that you are in, and I don't have a good answer for you.  I was just thinking about this, however: Looking at it from the other person's point of view, if that person had come to our site and posted a question saying that he's been getting voicemail messages about how he received some money in error and needs to send it back, there would be 5 answers here that would tell him that it is a scam and he should ignore the voicemail messages.  That is probably why your calls are not getting returned.

Comment: You'll probably need to find someone that can help you contact this person to get it straightened out.  If he has a Chase bank account, hopefully you can find someone at Chase that is willing to help you.  Otherwise, you could try calling the police and see if they would be willing to help.  It doesn't hurt to ask.  If not, perhaps an attorney could help, if it is worth it to spend the money on legal fees.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it but it sounds like Chase sent the money to the right account, but you entered the wrong number.  I'm not terribly well versed in Chase's terms of service but I'd say you're probably on your own.  With that said, the person who received the money has done nothing for it and legally should return it.  Obviously it's difficult to trace a phone number to a name and/or address but if you were able to match the person I'd imagine a stern letter on a legal letter head would be enough to have the person return the money.